# Deleting Users from Salesforce permanently

Tags: user, delete, user-record, deactivate

Its been quite while that a large number of Users were Deactivated and not need them anywhere in ORG. And the user list who were deactivated getting piled up to a heap now. Couple of users never logged into the system as well before deleting, seems like created incorrectly. Is there a way to Permanently remove a User details from Salesforce?

I know that as per all standard Salesforce Docs its mentioned that its only allowed to Deactivate/Freeze a user and not able to Delete/Purge it.

Just checking is there any possibility for this Delete/Purge permanently in any advanced level or something? Or raising a case with Salesforce team and they can do something, Any comments on this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As of today, there's still no way to do that. You can, however vote on [this idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000IxWGAA0), that's currently on review.

Comment: Thnx for the Voting link for the Idea.. I just voted for this idea.. And will be sharing this link as well for those who thinks this is needed... I definitely believe that this is needed in near future.   https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000IxWGAA0&sort=2

Answer (score 4):

Those who thinks that this Delete feature is required for Deleting unwanted user details from Salesforce please click on below Link to Vote for the Idea. Currently this Idea is under "PRODUCT TEAM REVIEW". I believe this is a cool feature that all Admins required now or in near future.

- [Click to Vote for this Idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000IxWGAA0&sort=2)

Attaching a screen shot of this as below.
[image]